# How can I update a specific field of a document, one by one, while iterating over all the documents?

Tags: python, mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo

I have documents in a collection, and each document is (say) like this:

```
doc: {
'dflag':0
'name':
'address':
}
```

While iterating over, that is:

```
query = {"dflag":0}
for doc in mydb["mycol"].find(query):
    -do-something-
    ...
    # want to change 'dflag' of this particular doc, from 0 to 1
    newvalue = { "$set": { "dflag": 1 } }
    doc.update(newvalue)
```

I want to update 'dflag' of each document one by one, but, doing it like above is not working.
How can I update a specific field of a document, one by one, while iterating over all the documents?

Comment: Use the [update_one](https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/pymongo/collection.html?highlight=.save()#pymongo.collection.Collection.update_one) method to save changes.

Comment: what do you've to read + iterate + update ? two DB calls ? Instead of using `.update()` to do this in one DB call..

Comment: What I am doing is reading each document, then processing it in "-do-something-" part. I have used try and except, if code in "-do-something-" part runs successfully, I am updating that  document's dflag = 1 and, if code fails for this particular document  then, I am not updating its dflag value.
If I can do it without making two DB calls, please do guide me, I will be grateful to you @whoami

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with `update` method

```
doc.update(query, newvalue)
```

Also, you can use `update_one` to update the first element that matched the query.

```
one.update_one(query, newvalue)
```